# hidden file consuming disk space

Tags: linux, logging

The following file is consuming a lot of disk space. Can I remove this file?

```
/opt/wlt-tomcat/logs/.catalina.out.swp
```

What this file is used for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a swap file used by vi/vim. You can remove it if you're not editing `/opt/wlt-tomcat/logs/.catalina.out` in vi/vim.

Comment: vim should remove it automatically when it exits, though.

Comment: When it exits cleanly, yes.